# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://superuser.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Are we allowed to nominate someone else?

Comment: @Nifle: no, because when one goes to nominate, the title says "nomination form for studiohack" or something like that...

Answer (score 6):

## Edit: Everyone getting nervous yet? :D

I think it's rather disappointing you only get to (And are allowed to in the first place) nominate yourself. I think such a nomination should be done by the community. Especially because you'll get a lot of nice sales talks when individual contribution should be evaluated.

Furthermore, I think nominations should be kept invisible to prevent community nominees in such a system to suddenly start working their butts off to get elected.

To be honest, I wouldn't have nominated myself if there was any other way to get nominated...

Comment: @BloodPhilia: invisible how?

Comment: @studiohack as in, someone nominated **someone else**, and the nominated person or anyone alse for that matter won't be able to see who was nominated. Like, silent community nomination instead of open self nomination.

Comment: I agree with you that nominations should be just that... nominations from others.  However I don't think any activity that candidates may do in the next couple of weeks will really "prove" their worth.  You can tell if a candidate is worthy by the fact that they've put *time* into this, and if they all of a sudden start activity then that is also prevalent as well.

Comment: @BloodPhilia: ah, makes more sense! +1 I agree that it should be nominations by someone else...

Comment: @KronoS 'tis true, yet I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: @BloodPhilia sure do and I agree with you for the most part.

Comment: @BloodPhilia: People have to stand up and speak for themself, this is just like in real life politics. Otherwise you would come up with nominations for people that might not want to be nominated, and people that don't have their activity and mind towards moderating. Just as an example: Looking through the first pages of users there are quite some users that are doing a lot of effort on asking and answering questions, but they might simply not have had past interest in actual moderation... Furthermore, visible nominations tend to lead to a high quality. You can't list things you don't perform.

Comment: But, I'm neutral about this and this has been well though out in the past so I don't think changing the current election is a wise thing to do. But anyhow, if more people agree on this then I guess there can be improved. Subjectively seen, there was kind of a system bias when you were down-voted early in the previous version. And again subjectively seen, this might be a system bias too as it might get a bit more random... But in the end, the users have to choose: They can ask you to nominate yourself, you can show that you have what it takes and then they can vote for you...

Comment: There's always going to be someone that doesn't like it, but his/her next nomination might be better... Not everyone can be elected to be a moderator in a single election, so may the best ones win.

Comment: @Blood Re: your edit, Yes :P

Comment: @Sathya ***Evil laugh***

Answer (score 4):

[After the example of the Math.SE site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/list-of-questions-for-candidates-in-2010-moderator-election) I have some questions that I would love to see each nominee respond to in their nomination (if they choose to do so):

- Is there anything you would want to change on the site? And how would you plan on achieving this?
- How do you expect becoming a moderator will change or influence the way you use Super User?
- What's your stance on duplicates and how should they be handled?
- What's your opinion about the overlap between Super User and Apple.SE/Ubuntu.SE? And when should questions be migrated from Super User to any of these other SE-sites?
- Which three nominees do you think are the most suited to become the next moderators and why?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's better to have a separate question instead, if everyone is going to answer this the nominations might get TL;DR...

Comment: I can, but it's up to the nominees to use it as they see fit

Answer (score 2):

At The Stack Overflow Blog:

> Trilogy 2011 Elections Begin
>
> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/trilogy-2011-elections-begin/

*Contains more info on the election process, etc.  Check it out!*